# Hive count distinct UDAF

Tags: hive, query-optimization, hiveql

I ran into a Hive query calculating a `count distinct` without grouping, which runs very slow. So I was wondering how is this functionality implemented in Hive, is there a `UDAFCountDistinct` for this?

Answer (score 1):

Hive 1.2.0+ provides [auto-rewrite optimization for count(distinct)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10568). Check this setting:

```
hive.optimize.distinct.rewrite=true;
```